# extract all text (include space and carriage return) between two word with regex perl

Tags: regex, perl

```
my $example=<<EO_STR;

Start

text1 

text2 


text3 Text4

Text5 text6

text7

End

EO_STR
```

on the following exemple. I want to extract all the text between Start and End(knowing that the text text extract contains spaces and new line and return charriot)

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
$example=~m/start\s+(.*?)\s+end/i
```

Comment: A belated welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54692932/edit) to include more information.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: I already mentioned my code that I tried to do, 
but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line ending, i.e. `\n`, is a white space, so this can simply be written as

```perl
$example =~ /(?i:start)([\w\s]+)(?i:end)/
```

Is there a particular reason `start` and `end` have to be matched case-insensitive? Your example indicates that the regex might be simplified to:

```perl
$example =~ /Start([\w\s]+)End/
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution thanks to you all

```
$example=~m/start([a-zA-Z0-9\p{P}\p{S} \s]*)end/i;
```